# how to say 'nerd' or 'geek' in french?

Tags: argot

It seems there's no agreement in french forums what is the right translation.

People brought up

> pingouin/trolleur

but others claimed those are degoratory and inaccurate terms, and more about
internet trolling, and proposed

> un informaniaque or un ordinaccro

instead.

which of those is in wide use? 
or perhaps french people use the English words?

Comment: I'm french and never heard pingouin in that context, and never heard "informaniaque" or "ordinaccro" at all. "trolleur" or just "troll" is used to mean troll, just as in English.

Comment: @Pierre what about "nul"? linguee.com translates nerd as nul :  "Would you view your friend as an oddball, a drag, or a nerd?" -
*Considèreriez-vous votre ami/e comme quelqu'un de farfelu, casse-pieds ou nul ?*

Comment: Being *nul* usually means being bad at something, I don't see any matter with *geek* or *nerd* here.

Comment: For quite a lot of people [nerds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerd) and [geeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geek) are different (debate [here](https://slackprop.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/on-geek-versus-nerd/) or [here](https://www.wired.com/2009/07/great-geek-debates-geek-vs-nerd/), plenty more out there). We usually welcome one question at a time, so you should have two different questions. Moreover the question about geek had already been asked. I hesitated on the reason for closing, it could have been for the "too broad" reason.

Comment: @bebe as others replied, "nul" can be used for anything. Either to say being bad at something, or plain, uninteresting, boring... In that sense it could be used as "looser", so in some contexts replace a pejorative use of nerd/geek. But it never holds the positive sides of those words (passionate for nerd, technical for geek).

Comment: There's no agreement in English about the meaning of these words and whether they are synonyms (e.g. https://xkcd.com/747/). 'Nerd' can mean 'premier de la classe', but that's probably not what you're after.

Comment: In _Breaking Bad_, Gale Boetticher quotes a whole poem from Walt Whitman to Walter White, and then jokingly concludes : “Yes I'm a nerd!” So “_nul_” is definitely not a good translation, as “nerd”, on the contrary, qualifies someone who is highly competent in a rather narrow field of knowledge, or in a field that is not considered “popular” (which usually means : _a kind of knowledge that won't help to score some pussy_ — sorry). Perhaps “_obsessionnel_” would convey the idea, but it's too derogatory (and I like this quote : “Obsession is a term the lazy use to describe the dedicated”).

Comment: “_Intello_” would seem right for “nerd” (that's how I was called as a child... didn't like it much, but it was still better than “_balai à chiottes_”... o_O).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Geek** is commonly understood in french (at least by < 60 years) and should be the word **to use 90% of time** (and almost always when linked to IT/computers/videogames), you can say also 'passionné d'informatique' or 'fan de spider-man'.

- 'Geek' is mainly used for computer/IT in France but could be use in the same way than in US/UK for most young people.
- 'Passionné' might be use with anything
- 'fan' is more linked to music/movies/characters

**Nerd** is not really used in france (but's seems to be use in Quebec). One translation could be for France/Belgium:

'neuneu' or
'neuneu informaticien'

Please note that this is **pejorative**, and usually not said to the Nerd people directly (at least when you don't know him/her)

Comment: Nerd is used in Quebec french. Maybe even more than geek. Connotation is a bit more around school results than hacking abilities, though.

Comment: You're right, I edited the post to add this

Answer (score 5):

We indeed use the english word *geek*, however *nerd* is probably less widely used.

I don't see any good translation in french, that's often the case with IT related words, for example *Cloud* or *Machine learning* are used almost all the time in english.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99683/discussion-on-answer-by-stbr-how-to-say-nerd-or-geek-in-french).

Answer (score 2):

Le mot « geek » est fréquemment employé littéralement en France. Cependant, je ne recommande pas son utilisation, comme beaucoup d'autres mots anglais, parce que les phrases perdent leur clarté et leur intelligibilité.

Le mot « troll » par exemple est employé à mauvais escient pour exprimer des significations variables et subjectives.

Autre exemple, le « PC » désigne un ordinateur ayant une architecture de type IBM PC. C'est l'abréviation anglaise de « Personal Computer » ce qui signifie littéralement « ordinateur personnel ». Pourtant, on entends fréquemment des personnes dire « je préfère avoir un Mac plutôt qu'un PC ».

Mon avis est qu'on perd des connections (sens, analogie...) entre le mot et la langue française.